# Merge rows in a CSV file containing similar strings

Tags: python, csv, powerbi

I have a single CSV file loaded into Power Bi scraped from Python containing property names, addresses, and age but their addresses sometime vary. I want to merge rows that contain similar strings ex: Portland, Maine and Portland should be merged into one row.

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqcFy.png)

Comment: Seems you're looking for what's called a fuzzy matching/searching algorithm

Comment: I've looked into it but apparently it only applies to merging 2 or more CSV files.